# Convert from one promise type to another

Tags: swift, promisekit

If I have one function which returns a promise and calls another function which also returns a promise, is it possible to convert between the two without doing this...

```
func f1() -> Promise<Any?> { ... }

func f2() -> Promise<Void> {

   return f1().then { value -> Void in

      ...
   }
}
```

If I don't have the `.then` call, the compiler cannot convert from one type to another.

Comment: When you say "without doing this," what syntax did you have in mind? What part are you trying to remove?

Comment: The call to `then`. I was thinking of a cast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. First, generics aren't covariant in Swift. You can't pass a `[String]` where you expect an `[Any]`, so you can't convert from `Promise<Void>` to `Promise<Any?>`. In your case it's even worse, since you're trying to convert from `Promise<Any?>` to `Promise<Void>`, and a `Any?` is not a `Void`.

You may be thinking of `Void` as somehow special, like it means "nothing" in a magical, compiler way. That's not what `Void` is. It's just a typealias for the empty tuple (`()`). You can't convert from `Any?` to `()`. Imagine if you could do that. Then I could write this:

```
var list: [Void] = [] // This is just as legal as Promise<Void>
f2().then { x: Void in
    list.append(x)
}
```

Now I've appended some random Optional onto my array of `()`. That's going to crash and the compiler won't save me.

<strike>You could of course create a helper to do this if you wanted, like:</strike>

```
extension Promise {
    func ignoringResult() -> Promise<Void> {
        return self.then { _ in }
    }
}
```

And then you could write:

```
func f2() -> Promise<Void> {
    return f1().ignoringResult()
}
```

PromiseKit already has this converter: `Promise.asVoid()`.

Comment: That's great. `asVoid` is much cleaner.